# Suspend a publisher

Tags: ros, topic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! In my system there are 2 nodes that publish on a topic concurrently.
This situation leads an unstable state for my system, so I would suspend publication (only for that topic) from one of the two nodes.
I wouldn't work on the code of two nodes.
There is a way to pause the subscribtion of a publisher to a topic?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257049/suspend-a-publisher/) by [jony](https://answers.ros.org/users/29670/jony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With a topic_tools mux you can feed both inputs into a node and select which gets published out with a service call:

http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/mux

So instead of

```
node1 -> topicA 
node2 -> topicA
topicA -> node3
```

it would be

```
node1 -> topicB -> mux
node2 -> topicC -> mux
mux -> topicA  (which is a copy of either B or C depending on mux selection)
topicA -> node3
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jony](https://answers.ros.org/users/29670/jony/) on 2017-03-15**:
thank you for the answer, but following your suggestion I should work on the code of node1 and node2 to divert respectively node1 to topic B and node2 to topicC. Right?
In this case your solution isn't good for me.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-03-15**:
You don't have to alter the code to change where publications go, remapping can change that at runtime: http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments or http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap

**Comment by [jony](https://answers.ros.org/users/29670/jony/) on 2017-03-16**:
Great! It works. Thank you so much ;)